# Image of a unit ball under unbounded linear functional is complex plane

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $\phi$ is a linear functional that is not bounded on a Banach space $\mathcal H$. Prove that $$\phi (B_1) = \mathbb C$$ where $B_1=\{x \in \mathcal H ; \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is the closed unit ball.

I have  the intuitive idea for this, but I can't express this mathematically. As any point in the close unit ball can be scaled to the whole space through linearity, but how to prove it mathematically?

What I did is: Since $\phi$ is unbounded, so we have, for every $M$, there exist $x \in B_1$ such that $$|\phi (x)| \geq M ||x||$$ Since $\phi$ is linear, so we can choose $||x||=1$ instead of $||x|| \leq 1$.

Now for any $z \in \mathbb C$, $||z||=m$ for some $m$. So there exist $x$ such that $$ |\phi (x)| > m $$So by linearity we have a disc of radius large enough so that $m$ lies in $B$. $\implies$ there exist $y \in B_1$ such that $$ \phi (y) = z  \, \, \, and \, \, \, |\phi(y)|=m \in B$$ $\implies$ for every $z \in \mathbb C$ there exist $x \in B_1$ such that $\phi (x) = z$.

Is that enough for proof? please check this and give suggestions. And give the correct way to prove this if my proof is not correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\sup_{x\in B_{1}}|\phi(x)|=+\infty$ because $\phi$ is unbounded. Does this help?

Comment: By scalar multiplication with a complex number of modulus $1$ if we get a non zero value in the image, we get the whole circle that contains  it; by linearity we get also the inside disc; but now unbounded means you get values of arbitrarily  high modulus in the image so conclude